# Нужно ли тире в предложении:

Tags: пунктуация

Смотри, дорогая, звёзды (?) огромны!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**СмотрИ, дорогая, // звёзды  огрОмны!**

В предложении такой структуры знак не нужен.

Здесь две фразы (каждая со своим с тоническим ударением) и обособленное обращение  со вставочной интонацией.

Comment: С __тоническим__ ударением?.. Что это такое?

Comment: Фраза - это речевой отрезок с повышением или понижением тона на ударном слоге одного из слов. Это изменение ТОНА называется тоническим или фразовым ударением. В случае нейтральной интонации (без логического выделения слов) тоническое ударение падает на последнее слово фразы.

Comment: А, а я-то думал это то, которое в китайском и японском... Что ж, ясно, спасибо.